# Toggle in Repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the repeater i can expand the row(class header) on clcik and on if click again it will collapse.This is working fine.

I can expand and collapse all rows in same time.I want to expand one row(class header) at a time.if row1 is opened and if i click the row2 (class header),then row1 must automaticly collapse and row 2 must expand.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot.Now when i click row1 it is expanding and when i click row2 ,then row1 is collapsing and row2 is expanding. But when i click the row1(class header) is expanding but when i click row1 again it must collapse also.that is not working

```
<script language="JavaScript">



function ToggleDisplay(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('d' + id);
    if (elem) {
        if (elem.style.display != 'block') {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
```

```
<style>
    .header { font-size: larger; font-weight: bold; cursor: hand; cursor:pointer;
           background-color:#cccccc; font-family: Verdana; }
  .details { display:none; visibility:hidden; 
             font-family: Verdana; }
</style>

    &nbsp;<div style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;background-color:gray; height: 500px; width: 895px">

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

         <ItemTemplate>


 <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
      onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none;">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#79FFFF">

    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "License")%> 
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>

   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem," Date")%>
  </asp:Panel> 
 </div>

 <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

  <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Maroon">
  <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="License Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>

            </asp:Panel>

 </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Don't tag a question with vb.net, when the question is about javascript and your code doesn't contain a single vb.net line...

Comment: Check my answer - I think it might be what you are looking for :) FYI - you had your code pasted (selected as code) badly - I edited that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) ? - firstly add a class to each row(probably .details?) and then do something like:

**jQuery:**

```
function toggleDisplay(id) {
   $('.details').hide();
   $('#d'+id).show();
}
```

*However if you can not use jQuery for whatever reason - there is also a class-like solution in pure javascript...*
**pure JavaScript:**

```
function ToggleDisplay(id) {
    var allDetails = document.getElementsByClassName('details');
    var detaisToShow = document.getElementById('d' + id);
    for(var i=0; i<allDetails.length; i++){
        allDetails[i].style.display = 'none';
        allDetails[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    detaisToShow.style.display = 'block';
    detaisToShow.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

And here's a working fiddle with a hope-so desired behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/WFUMU/

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now when i click row1 it is expanding and when i click row2 ,then row1 is collapsing and row2 is expanding.             But when i click the row1(class header)  is expanding but when i click row1 again it must collapse also.that is not working